# Dataframe from dict of lists of varying length

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict as follows :

```
d = {1: ['A'], 2: ['A', 'B'], 3: ['B', 'C']}
```

(each value is a list of an arbitrary number of items chosen from a given list, here `['A', 'B', 'C']`)

I cannot find a simple way to obtain the following DataFrame:

```
  A B C
1 1 0 0
2 1 1 0
3 0 1 1
```

Is there a built-in way to do so ?

Edit: the list of all possible values (here : ['A', 'B', 'C']) is available to me

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to transform the dictionary a bit to be able to convert it to the DataFrame as you have given.

Example using dictionary comprehension for Python 2.7+ -

```
d = {k:{kv:v.count(kv) for kv in ['A','B','C']} for k,v in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T
```

Or in a single line -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k:{kv:v.count(kv) for kv in ['A','B','C']} for k,v in d.items()}).T
```

Demo -

```
In [18]: d = {1: ['A'], 2: ['A', 'B'], 3: ['B', 'C']}

In [19]: d = {k:{kv:v.count(kv) for kv in ['A','B','C']} for k,v in d.items()}

In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame(d).T

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   A  B  C
1  1  0  0
2  1  1  0
3  0  1  1
```

Comment: That is also true :-)

Comment: Would the downvoter mind commenting on the reason for the downvote, that is the only way I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin way to do what you want, this will get the counts efficiently and get all possible values without manually inputting, create a dict that stores `Counter` dicts which has the counts of values, then iterate over the list of unique possible values and do a lookup in the Counter:

```
d = {1: ['A'], 2: ['A', 'B',"B"], 3: ['B', 'C',"C"]}
from collections import Counter

unique = list(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
out = {}
counts = {k: Counter(v) for k, v in d.items()}
for k, v in d.items():
    cnt = counts[k]
    out[k] = {k:cnt[k] for k in unique}
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(df.T)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
1  1  0  0
2  1  2  0
3  0  1  2
```

A `Counter` approach is considerably more efficient than using `list.count`.

If you only had one of each value using a set approach would be sufficient:

```
unique = set(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
out = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    un = unique.difference(v)
    out[k] = {k: 0 if k in un else 1 for k in unique}
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

A universal algorithm for any number of values:

```
d = {1: ['A'], 2: ['A', 'B'], 3: ['B', 'C']}
# list of unique values
unique = list(set([v for val in d.values() for v in val]))

print ' ', ' '.join([str(i) for i in unique])
for k, v in d.items():
    print k, u' '.join([str(1 if unique[i] in v else 0) for i in xrange(len(unique))])
```

Comment: This is basically just a less efficient what I already have in my answer, why use a set if you are not going to take advantage of it?

Comment: Why call list on it and index instead of simply iterating over the set? Using in makes the loop quadratic so it is basically the same as using count

Answer (score -1):

You can simply:

```
d = {1: ['A'], 2: ['A', 'B'], 3: ['B', 'C']}

print '  A B C'
for key,value in d.iteritems():
    print key, value.count('A'), value.count('B'), value.count('C')
```

Output:

```
  A B C
1 1 0 0
2 1 1 0
3 0 1 1
```

You can easily generalize the code to iterate on all available values for all keys.

Comment: A downvote without an explanation won't help anyone improving himself, too bad things like that are still happening.